# Can React props contain custom classes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

We have a (TypeScript) class that manages a set of parameters (contains parameter type, default/min/max values, descriptions, ...) that we are using in quite a few places in our code.
For our GUI we have started to use React. One of the components we're building is essentially some kind of parameter property panel, and for the props of my component I would like to use our custom ParameterSet class.

Should this just work? Or do props need to be simple types?
Does React do internal things that will stop working properly when props contain custom classes that are more complex than simple types?

Comment: props is just an object. It can contain anything you give it. There's no magic going on here

Comment: So there is no internal React-specific action going on that checks props (for example if they have changed etc...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @Rob has commented you, props can store whatever. You have to see them like an object that can have unlimited named references.

You can [validate their types](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#react.proptypes) (if you want), which when running your app in development will let you know if these types are correct:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  element: React.PropTypes.element.isRequired,
}
```

You can watch for changes, see React [lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#updating):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  // handle props change
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the confirmation!
I think I read somewhere that propTypes is not really needed when working with TypeScript, as that already provides for type checking. And our own ParameterSet class adds other checking itself as well.

Comment: @KoenT_IM I believe you are right, especially since `propTypes` validating will not even work under production. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4833#issuecomment-141040237